# Use setTextSize in proportion to screen

Tags: android, textview, size

I need a way for my textview look the same size in proportion to the screen using

```
settextsize()
```

Comment: Use "sp" for text size and "dp" for layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can achieve that is using `sp` as the unit of measure for your text. `sp` is a scale independent measurement unit which will make easier to integrate your text within different devices with different sizes and resolutions. As of the reference:

> **sp**
>
> Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

You'll see more info on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) and this [reference link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) will help you too.

**---- EDIT ----**

To set your size programmatically, you can use something like this:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
```

That would set the equivalent to `12sp` to your text size.

Comment: Thanks my friend, but does not work, the textview not resized when screen change

Comment: The solution I've provided doesn't make your text resize if the screen changes, it's just a way of defining the text size independently to the size physical size and resolution. If you meant **orientation**, you can use the `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` property.

Comment: Thanks, but i used in my code this: `metrics = getApplicationContext(). getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float Textsize =txt_pri.getTextSize()/metrics.density`; but doesn't work,I am not referring to the orientation of the screen.